# Execute multiple framework7 router functions back to back

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I am building an app where a user can submit a form using ajax and the form will submit and upon success will go back to the previous page and then load two more pages. Here is a little bit more info before I get to my code snippet

I have a list of items and want to add another item. I have a button that will open up an add item form. When I submit the form with AJAX and upon success I want to :

1. Go back to the list of items in history `mainView.router.back()` to refresh with newest item and then
2. Go to the item page `mainView.router.loadPage()` and then
3. Go to a task for that item automatically which is another page `mainView.router.loadPage()`

I want all these three actions done at once one after the other. Going back will prevent the user from using the back button and getting back at the form that has already been submitted, going to the item page will be there in case the user does not want to perform the default action of starting a task for the item. I have successfully tested and can perform any **ONE** of these actions, but cannot figure out how to call the router functions one after the other simultaneously.

```
...
var item_id = data.newItem.id;
mainView.router.back({
  url: page.view.history[page.view.history.length - 2],
  force: true,
  ignoreCache: true
});
mainView.router.loadPage('http://app.myapp. com/item.php?id='+item_id);
mainView.router.loadPage('http://app.myapp.com/start-item-task.php?id='+item_id);
...
```

Comment: I've never used the framework7, but it seems that you want to prevent an user from going back with a button in his browser after he posts the form, and that is framework agnostic problem. I don't know how framework7 pushes or updates browser history, but what I would try to do is: You have 3 pages: item, form-edit, item-tasks. The flow is: item-tasks -> item -> item-edit (POST) -> item-tasks. IMO what you need to do is just don't push history update when you enter item-edit page. So from history perspective: item-tasks -> item -> item-tasks.

Comment: @Oskar Framework7 works a little bit different than what you are thinking. The new pages are loaded inside of a div on the current page and keeps in history div the other pages. The browser back buttons do absolutely nothing. And when opened as an chrome app there is no browser back button.